# Is there a complete list of lazy functions of Clojure's core module?

Tags: clojure

After a while of working with Clojure, I have accumulated some knowledge on its *laziness*. I know whether a frequently-used API such as *map* is lazy. However, I still feel dubious when I start using an unfamiliar API such as *with-open*.

Is there any document that shows a complete list of lazy APIs of Clojure's core module?

Comment: I think you're a bit confused about the concept of laziness in Clojure. There are no lazy functions, only lazy sequences. Plus, `with-open` is not a function at all; it's a macro. The question of whether `with-open` is a lazy function makes no sense with that information in mind.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find functions that return lazy sequences by opening up the Clojure code https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/clj/clojure/core.clj
and searching for "Returns a lazy"

I am not aware of any curated lists of them.

The rule of thumb is: if it returns a sequence, it will be a lazy sequence, if it returns a value, it will force evaluation.

When using a new function, macro or special form, read the docstring. Most development environments have a key to show the docstring, or at least navigate to the source (where you can see the docstring), and there is always http://clojure.org/api/api.

In the case of with-open:

with-open
macro
Usage: (with-open bindings & body)
bindings => [name init ...]

Evaluates body in a try expression with names bound to the values
of the inits, and a finally clause that calls (.close name) on each
name in reverse order.

We can see that the result of calling with-open is evaluation of the expression with a final close. So we know that there is nothing lazy about it. However that doesn't mean you don't need to think about laziness inside with-open, quite the opposite!

```
(with-open [r (io/reader "myfile")]
  (line-seq r))
```

This is a common trap. `line-seq` returns a lazy sequence! The problem here is that the lazy sequence will be realized after the file is closed, because the file is closed when exiting the scope of `with-open`. So you need to fully process the lazy sequence before exiting the with-open scope.

My advice is to avoid trying to think about your program as having 'lazy bits' and 'immediate bits', but instead just be mindful that when io or side-effects are involved you need to take care of when things happen as well as what should happen.

Answer (score 4):

digging on a Timothy Pratley's proposal to search in doc:

let's make it fun!

your repl has everything that you need to find out a list of lazy functions.

first of all, there is a `clojure.repl/doc` macro, which prints documentation to *out* in repl

```
user> (doc +)
-------------------------
clojure.core/+
([] [x] [x y] [x y & more])
  Returns the sum of nums. (+) returns 0. Does not auto-promote
  longs, will throw on overflow. See also: +'
nil
```

unfortunately we can't get a string of it simply, but we can always rebind the `*out*` to be a `StringWriter`, and then get its string value.

so, whan we want to take all the symbols from `clojure.core` namespace, get their docs, write them all to string, and find every one that contains "returns a lazy". Here comes the help: `clojure.core/ns-publics`, returning a map of public names to their vars:

```
user> (take 10 (ns-publics 'clojure.core))
([primitives-classnames #'clojure.core/primitives-classnames] 
 [+' #'clojure.core/+'] 
 [decimal? #'clojure.core/decimal?] 
 [restart-agent #'clojure.core/restart-agent] 
 [sort-by #'clojure.core/sort-by] 
 [macroexpand #'clojure.core/macroexpand] 
 [ensure #'clojure.core/ensure] 
 [chunk-first #'clojure.core/chunk-first] 
 [eduction #'clojure.core/eduction] 
 [tree-seq #'clojure.core/tree-seq])
```

so we just need to get all the keys from there and lookup for their docs.
Let's make a macro for that:

```
user> (defmacro all-docs []
        (let [names (keys (ns-publics 'clojure.core))]
          `(binding [*out* (java.io.StringWriter.)]
             (do ~@(map #(list `doc %) names))
             (str *out*))))
#'user/all-docs
```

it does just what i've said, gets all publics' docs to string.

now we simply process it:

```
user> (def all-doc-items (clojure.string/split 
                           (all-docs) 
                           #"-------------------------"))
#'user/all-doc-items

user> (nth all-doc-items 10)
"\nclojure.core/tree-seq\n([branch? children root])\n  Returns a lazy sequence of the nodes in a tree, via a depth-first walk.\n   branch? must be a fn of one arg that returns true if passed a node\n   that can have children (but may not).  children must be a fn of one\n   arg that returns a sequence of the children. Will only be called on\n   nodes for which branch? returns true. Root is the root node of the\n  tree.\n"
```

and now just filter them:

```
user> (def all-lazy-fns (filter #(re-find #"(?i)returns a lazy" %) all-doc-items))
#'user/all-lazy-fns

user> (count all-lazy-fns)
30

user> (println (take 3 all-lazy-fns))
(
clojure.core/tree-seq
([branch? children root])
  Returns a lazy sequence of the nodes in a tree, via a depth-first walk.
   branch? must be a fn of one arg that returns true if passed a node
   that can have children (but may not).  children must be a fn of one
   arg that returns a sequence of the children. Will only be called on
   nodes for which branch? returns true. Root is the root node of the tree.

clojure.core/keep-indexed
([f] [f coll])
  Returns a lazy sequence of the non-nil results of (f index item). Note,
  this means false return values will be included.  f must be free of
  side-effects.  Returns a stateful transducer when no collection is
  provided.

clojure.core/take-nth
([n] [n coll])
  Returns a lazy seq of every nth item in coll.  Returns a stateful
  transducer when no collection is provided.
)
nil
```

And now use these `all-lazy-fns` however you want.